# Fullscreen TMUX session selection

Tags: tmux

I've found [TMUX](http://tmux.github.io/)'s `choose-tree` command to be quite useful when navigating between sessions, but I dislike it only displaying inside of the current pane. I'd prefer it to overtake my entire screen.

Inside my `tmux.conf` I'm attempting to write something to do just that, but haven't quite figured it out:

```
# ~/.tmux.conf
bind-key a resize-pane -Z \; choose-tree
```

My trigger command `Ctrl-a + a` will zoom the current tmux pane to be fullscreen and run choose-tree inside of it. Unfortunately this leaves the pane zoomed in.

Any ideas how I can unzoom the pane afterwards, or a different approach for fullscreen TMUX session selection?

Answer (score 0):

You can do `choose-tree -Z` to open in zoomed mode.